# About Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Why the `max`, `min`, `count` aggregate functions don't give proper output when used against a column of datatype `varchar(max)` in SQL Server 2005?

Please tell me friends

Comment: Can you show us some code that illustrates your point?

Comment: But they do give proper output (at least every time I have used them).  Why do you think the results are not correct?

Comment: i am having the max value is 100 in that field and min value is 16.355 and number of rows is 46.while i am executing min it gives 100  and for max it gives 63.457 and for count it gives 45 only..if that the field has one or more values same these problem may occur..?

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the minimum or maximum to be based on the decimal value of what is stored in a VARCHAR(MAX) column, you would have to CAST this column to DECIMAL first. Eg:

```
SELECT
  MIN( CAST(val AS DECIMAL(28,4) ) AS min_val
FROM
  your_table
```

This will only work if this VARCHAR column only contains numerical values. In this case it would be better to change the type of this column to an appropriate DECIMAL type in the first place. Then you would not have to CAST in the first place.

Selecting a MIN or MAX on a VARCHAR column will select the [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) minimum/maximum and thus takes the length of the string into account.

Comment: @DhandsDhands You can thank me most by checking the check mark.